# Embed aws iot device sdk to Micropython as user C module

Tags: c, sdk, embed, aws-iot, micropython

Since there's no official aws iot device sdk for micropython, I'd like to compile embed the [official C SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C) into micropython as a user module.

I following the guide from micropython official [documentation](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/develop/cmodules.html) on how to compile an external C modules into micropython.

The first method I'd like to use is `initializeMqtt()`. I added the include directories to the makefile (e.g.: `CFLAGS_USERMOD += -I$(LIBS)/$(OPENSSL_DIR)/include/`). Then I could compile it, but after I got some linker errors in connection with openssl. I cloned openssl from the official openssl Github page, and update the include directories, and started to add the missing .c files to the makefile, to compile it in. After I had the same results, and tried to found the missing references (search in openssl source), and I add the neccessary .c files, to the makefile (e.g.: `SRC_USERMOD += $(LIBS)/$(OPENSSL_DIR)/crypto/cryptlib.c`). Now I got more and more linking, errors like:

- undefined reference to `X509_VERIFY_PARAM_move_peername`.
- undefined reference to `tls1_set_groups_list`
  and so on.

I use MacOS, I have installed openssl, added the must have flags to .profile.

Is it even possible achieve what I want?

Comment: I would try asking about this on the [MicroPython forum](https://forum.micropython.org/).